# Check if image has title attribute, then apply to image selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't seem to be working for me. I want to perform these actions only on images with a title attribute set. It seems my problem is when I use `$(this)`, it is referring to the title attribute? Thanks in advance.

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    /* Run this only if images have a title attribute */
    if ($('.node-page img[title], .node-news img[title]')) {
      $(this).each(function() {
        var image = $(this);
        var caption = image.attr('title');
        var imagealign = image.css('float');

        image.after('<span class="caption">' + caption + '</span>');
        image.next('span.caption').andSelf().wrapAll('<div>');
        image.parent('div').addClass('caption-wrapper').css({'width': imagewidth, 'height': 'auto', 'float': imagealign});
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is no point in `$(this).each`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you got mixed-up with the `if` and the `each()`. You should apply your each to your selector directly. If no image have a `title` attribute then it won't do anything, else it will apply your function to each element.

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    /* Run this only on images that have a title attribute */
    $('.node-page img[title], .node-news img[title]').each(function() {
        var image = $(this);
        var caption = image.attr('title');
        var imagealign = image.css('float');

        image.after('<span class="caption">' + caption + '</span>');
        image.next('span.caption').andSelf().wrapAll('<div>');
        image.parent('div').addClass('caption-wrapper').css({'width': imagewidth, 'height': 'auto', 'float': imagealign});
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```